# Is there such thing as a plymouth IDE?

Tags: boot, plymouth, ide

I have googled and have scoured the internet attempting to find a plymouth script IDE which would allow me to see a sample window which update itself with code changes. Similar to Apple's XCode "Playground."

Is there any such thing? Or should I just stick with the good, old-fashioned text editor?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if it matters, and any help would be appreciated.